# Availability of name of a structure in C++

Tags: c++

Consider the following two code snippets (A and B in order):

```
struct abc {
    int a {};
    abc* next;
};
```

and

```
struct abc {
     int a {};
     abc next;
};
```

The facts are:
 1. Snippet A is valid.
 2. Snippet B is invalid.

Arguments:

B is invalid because the compiler is not able to determine the size of abc in snippet B at the time of declaration. (**Stroustrup, C++ Programming Language, 8.2.2**)

My Doubt:

Isn't the size of `abc` required during the compilation of snippet A? Is the size of `abc` not required when declaring the pointer to `abc`? Otherwise during compilation, how would the compiler know how to dereference `abc*`?

Comment: I think the reason might a recursion to calculate abc size. when compiler calculates size of abc, think about. try to calculate this equation: size(abc) = size(int{}) + size(abc)

Comment: The size of the pointer does not depend on the size of the type pointed to.

Comment: This is [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/) applied to software-development. A struct in a struct in a struct in a struct in a struct....

Comment: @HelloWorld Structception

Comment: Please do not write follow-up questions as edits to the original question. Create a new question--but first try to see if there is an existing post that answers your question.

Comment: Though the quick answer to your follow-up is that dereferencing *is* "using" a pointer. The distinction is between using and *declaring* a pointer. Your final sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: C++ has not had structures since 1985. When you write `struct`, you declare a _class_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ distinguishes between *declaration* and *usage*. To *declare* a pointer, the size of the pointee type doesn’t need to be known. However, the code that deferences the pointer does need to know its size.

Answer (score 7):

In your second example you have a class contain an instance of the same class which will, recursively, contain an instance of the same class.

Since every object in C++ must be of size of at least 1 this means that any instance of class `abc` will be infinite (1+1+1+...).

The first example isn't a problem since the size of a pointer to any object is a constant therefore the size of `abc` is finite and creating such an object can be done without creating infinite objects (the pointer can point to `nullptr` or to an existing object).

Comment: I much prefer this reasoning than the more-commonly-heard "size isn't known" shenanigans, though both are equally valid approaches.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To be fair, so do I.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Snippet B is that it doesn't just contain a pointer to another abc, it contains the memory allocation for an entire abc. Which, in turn, contains an entire abc. Which contains an entire abc. Which contains an entire abc. See where we're going with this?

Snippet A doesn't have this problem; it just stores a pointer of fixed size. That pointer may point to another valid abc, but it could just as well point to null, itself, a random point in memory, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Size of a variable is needed when using pointer arithmetic or deferencing using the [] operator.

At compile time you do not need the size of the referenced object when declaring a pointer to it.